# The 'ksp' configuration is deprecated in Kotlin Multiplatform projects. Please use target-specific configurations like 'kspJvm' instead

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

when I want to run `Compose Desktop` project i get this warning

```
The 'ksp' configuration is deprecated in Kotlin Multiplatform projects. Please use 
target-specific configurations like 'kspJvm' instead.
Invalid Java installation found at '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11' (Common Linux Locations). 
It will be re-checked in the next build. This might have performance impact if it keeps 
failing. Run the 'javaToolchains' task for more details.
```

how can I use `taget-specific` configurations like `KspJvm` ?